# Get reference to calling object in jquery autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I want to use the jquery ui autocomplete plugin with 2 controls, so I have this:

```
    $("#From, #To").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://example.com/search/" + $(this).val(),
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    featureClass: "P"
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.autocomplete, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.name + " (" + item.id + ")",
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem is that the url param where I use $(this).val() to get the text in the current textbox doesn't work, how can I do this in a way that I won't need to duplicate the autocomplete code for each control?

thanks!

Comment: That looks ok at first glance, put a breakpoint on it and run `$(this).attr("id")` to verify `this` is pointing to the correct object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `this.term` to get the search term that is to be used. You might also want to wrap this in `encodeURIComponent()` i.e.

```
url: "http://example.com/search/" + encodeURIComponent(this.term),
... // etc.
```

Comment: In this case `this` refers to the jQuery UI widget, i.e. the `autocomplete` instance. The `term` property is just set up by the `autocomplete` widget internally to hold the search term to use to filter down the auto-complete options. I just did a `console.log(this);` within the `success` `function` to find it :-)